# template operator ->

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to conviniently call template operator-> ?
It would be cool to have such possibility in classes like variant

For example: (thats just an example)

```
struct base_t
{
   template<class T>
   T* operator->()
   {
      return reinterpret_cast<T*>(this);
   }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   base_t x;
   x.operator-><std::pair<int,int>>()->first; //works, but inconvenient
   x<std::pair<int,int>>->first; // does not work
   x-><std::pair<int,int>>first; //does not work

   return 0;
}
```

I need proofs =)

Comment: "It would be cool to have such possibility in classes like variant" No, it would not. If you think so, consider the fact that a variant holds an object whose type is only known  *at runtime*.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yep, but you should use it with cautions. There are other places, where it could be used =) It is like `boost::get`, throwing exception. `Operator ->` also could throw exception.

Comment: It's not a matter of caution. It's a matter of *not making sense at all*. You cannot use a type determined at runtime in a compile-time construct like a template.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes There is no difference with current approaches of getting-pointer-calling-method. And type provided to `operator->` is known at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not real, how this it's not real too

```
struct base_t
{
   template<class T>
   T operator () ()
   {
      return T();
   }
};

int main()
{
   base_t x;
   x.operator ()<int>(); // works
   x.()<int>(); // not works
}
```

> An expression x->m is interpreted as (x.operator->())->m for a class object x of type T if T::operator->()
> exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism

> postfix-expression -> templateopt id-expression
>
> postfix-expression -> pseudo-destructor-name

So, syntax `x-><T>` is simply incorrect.

Comment: I understand, that I can do that many other ways. But does it somethere in standard?

Comment: Or this is limitation by grammar, provided in standard?

Comment: Okay, thanks, that what I wanted